# what is the match regex for string

Tags: regex

I have a string like below format:

```
<pre>
===
RESULTS (means and 95% confidence intervals)
---
Total: 1607.3ms +/- 7.6%
---

3d: 82.7ms +/- 43.6%
cube: 38.1ms +/- 37.5% 
</pre>
```

I would like to have output like this:
**Total: 1607.3**

i have used like this:

```
var reg = /\w.*:\D.*[ms]/gi
var result = "mytext".match(reg);
```

but how to avoid "ms in last?
what should be regex for this?

Comment: It depends on the language, but it would be something like <any number of any kind of character until>Total: <placeholder>ms<any number of any kind of character>, then you just pull out your placeholder and tack it to the end of a "Total: " string.

Comment: You really need to give more information for questions like this. Without a better idea of what sort of strings you'll be testing, `/Total: 1607\.3ms/` is a perfectly valid (and useless) answer to your question.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include the "flavor" of Regex you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The absolute simples solution I can think of would be:

```
Total:.*(?=ms)
```

If your output will always be in this format, the above regex should work for you.

The `(?=ms)` is called a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In this case it is looking for a string that is followed by a **ms** but will not include the **ms** in the match.

Answer (score 0):

This should match: `Total: \d+\.\d+ms`

Where `\d+` matches any number of digits, and `\.` matches the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Capture anything which is not a '`+`':

```
([^+]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If MULTILINE switch is supported then you can use this regex:

```
 /^Total: *[^ ]+/m
```

in `String#match` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Total: [0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

`/Total:\s*\d+\.\d+(?=ms)/` should do it for you.

Like other answers proposed, the Total: matches the text. But this pattern provides more flexibility in terms of white space after the "Total:" text, as well as a more flexibility in the amount of numeric characters before and after the decimal point. The positive lookahead at the end matches, but does not include, the "ms" text.

Hope this helps!